# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number in kendo ui grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid for my web portal
code for grid is

```
 //Grid for award adding
    var griddataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        dataType: "json",
        transport: {
            read: function(o){
                    //o.success([]);
                    url: ServiceBaseUrl+"/Magazine/getsubscriptiondetails?magazineid="+magazine_id, 
                    dataType: "json",
                },
            create: function(o) {                      
                var item = o.data;
                //assign a unique ID and return the record
                item.id =  len;
                o.success(item);
                len++;
            },
            destroy: function(o) {
                o.success();
            },
            update: function(o){
                o.success();
            }         
        },                      
        autoSync: false,
        schema: {                       
        model: {
        id    : "id",
        fields: {

                        magazine_subscription_id: { editable: true},
                        no_of_issues:{editable: true, type:"number", validation: {
                            required: {
                                message: "No of issues required"
                            },
                            min: 1
                        }
                        },
                        subscription_name: { editable: true, type:"string", validation: {
                            required: {
                                message: "Package Name required"
                            }
                            } 
                        },
                        subscription_key: { editable: true, type:"string", validation: { 
                            required: {
                                message: "Subscription Key required"
                            }
                        } },
                        price_inr: { type: "number", validation: { 
                            required: {
                                message: "Price(INR) Key required"
                            }, min: .1} },
                        price: { type: "number", validation: { 
                            required: {
                                message: "Price($) Key required"
                            },
                            min: .1} },
                        discount_type: { type:"string", editable: true, nullable: false},
                        discount_no_of_free_issue: { type: "number" ,validation: { min: 1}}

        }      
        }
        }
    });

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: griddataSource,
    pageable: false,
    selectable: "multiple",
    sortable: true,
    filterable: false,
    reorderable: true,
    scrollable: false,
    toolbar: ["create"],

    columns: 
    [
        { field: "no_of_issues", title: "No. of issues", width: "100px", format: ""},
        { field: "subscription_name", title: "Package Name", width: "150px" },
        { field: "subscription_key", title: "Subscription Key", width: "150px" },
        { field: "price_inr", title: "Price (INR)", width: "75px" },
        { field: "price", title: "Price ($)", width: "75px" },
        { field: "discount_type", title: "Type", width: "150px", values: type},
        { field: "discount_no_of_free_issue", title: "Discount / No. of Issues", width: "150px", format: ""},
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "210px" }
    ],
    editable: "inline"
    });
```

the grid display the content correctly. but when i add a new record in to the grid then show an error that

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

if any one know this please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

As I can see in [basic sample](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html) , parameter **width** of column definition should be a number instead of string

```
 { field: "no_of_issues", title: "No. of issues", width: 100 },
```

UPD: as Pavel Petrman said, now it's acceptable to use string width, to set proper scale. For example [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/local-data.html) author used "px", and you can use relative points ("100%") as well.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it, if you need to set width to % value, there's no other way... Certainly that doesn't cause the problem (first, I've tested it myself, second, when string comes, it can't be an unexpected number)

Comment: It's pretty old question, probably things changed and string acceptable now.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, thanks for pointing that  I just didn't pay attention to it initially. You may wish to edit your answer so that it remains valid at current state of things :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this very problem. The problem was very easy to solve yet very hard to track down. So I got rid of the error by supplying

```
create: function(options) {    
    options.success({ID:x});
}
```

where x is something valid (in my case it was a string).

Nevermind that something else is in the object:

```
options.success({ID:x, foo:bar, ... , stuff: {}, ...})
```

the important thing is the valid id that corresponds with your model id settings (again, in my case

```
schema: {
    model: {
       id: "ID",
```

).

So regarding this particular question, I'd check the `len` parameter.

Comment: ı read your solution but you must explain where you write that code and grid create not work this error while working

Answer (score 0):

I got this kind of error with the wrong column mapping. I had

```
 columns: [
 {
     field: 'Name',
     template: vm.categoryNameTreeTemplate
 },
 { field: 'Description' },
 { field: 'Category Code' }, -- this one is wrong
 { field: 'IsDeleted' },
 { command: ['create', 'edit'] }
]
```

but the correct version was

```
columns: [
 {
     field: 'Name',
     template: vm.categoryNameTreeTemplate
 },
 { field: 'Description' },
 { field: 'CategoryCode' },  -- correct
 { field: 'IsDeleted' },
 { command: ['create', 'edit'] }
]
```